# Positioning TikZ pictures in beamer slide

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, positioning

I am trying to position a TikZ picture on a `beamer` slide but some nodes (well, not all?) get pushed to the right.

I have tried to add `%` wherever it seemed fitting as mentioned in [Tikz figure in Beamer shifting way to the right of the frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26055/tikz-figure-in-beamer-shifting-way-to-the-right-of-the-frame), but that doesn't help.
I have tried the `adjustbox` which only resize the nodes but doesn't move them to the right. My head hurts so maybe you could help since I probably have missed something.
I can make things more or less work with the `textblock` environment but I think it's

Here is my MnotWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzstyle{block1} =[draw=black, fill=blue!40, rectangle, minimum height=0.25cm, minimum width=0.25cm, inner xsep=0.25cm, font=\bf\normalsize]
\tikzstyle{link} =[draw=blue, ultra thick]
\tikzstyle{box1} =[draw=blue, fill=white, ultra thick, rectangle, inner ysep=0.25cm, inner xsep=0.25cm, minimum height=0.25cm]
\tikzstyle{fancytitle1} =[fill=black, rounded corners, text=white]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node (preop) [block1] {blabla};
\node (op) [block1, right=.25cm of preop] {blabla};
\node (postop) [block1, right=.25cm of op] {blabla};
\node (posthp) [block1, right=.25cm of postop] {blabla};

\draw (preop) -- (op);
\draw (op) -- (postop);
\draw (postop) -- (posthp);

\node[box1, above= 2cm of preop] (box1) {%
   \begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}%
   \vspace{.5cm}%
     \begin{itemize}%
     \item tutu
     \item tete 
     \end{itemize}%
   \end{minipage}};

\node[fancytitle1, right=10pt] at (box1.north west) {Operation};
\draw[link] (op.north) -- (op|-box1.south);

\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Additionally:

1. I would like to have the `minipage` flush with the most left blabla node `(preop)`; and both somewhere close to the left hand side of my slide.
2. Can we position a node relatively by giving separate measures for vertical and horizontal distance? I know there is such a thing as `above left= 2 cm of XXX` but what if I want 1cm above and 2cm left?

Comment: The last sentence in the second paragraph is missing something...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is because of the left margin on the slide. If you wrap your `tikzpicture` in a `\makebox[\textwidth][c]{...}`, as explained in Martin Scharrer's answer to [Center figure that is wider than \textwidth](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16582/center-figure-that-is-wider-than-textwidth/16584#16584), it will be centered properly.

For your first additional question: Using `above = 2cm of preop.west, anchor=west` will align the Operation box with the left edge of the first `blabla` node.

For your second additional question: You can use `above left = 1cm and 2cm of <node>`.

Comment: @BiauDavid: If Jake's answer solves your problem, don't forget to upvote and accept it in order to 1) let everybody know 2) give Jake the reputation points he deserves and 3) get a couple of reputation point yourself.