# How to center a tikz figure in a beamer frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, horizontal-alignment, standalone

I was told to use the `standalone` package, which I use, but it does not seem to center the figure. What options to do I miss?

Concretely, here is the main file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}\frametitle{Title}
               \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
       \centering
       \includestandalone[
          mode=tex,
          width=1.3\textwidth,
          height=0.8\textheight
       ]{circle}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

While the included file is as simple as:

```
\documentclass[crop,preview,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}%
     \draw (0,0) circle (1cm);% 
  \end{tikzpicture}% 
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, this simple circle does not seem to be centered on the page.

[image: Output, showing that the included picture is not centered on the page]

~

Clarification: I do not mind the distortions, and the 130% scale is to demonstrate that the elongated circle is not centered, or else we would have the same overflow on both sides.

I believe that the output demonstrates that the included picture is vertically centered though.

BTW, this [Tikz figure in Beamer shifting way to the right of the frame](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26055/tikz-figure-in-beamer-shifting-way-to-the-right-of-the-frame?rq=1) seems to be related, but `\noindent` and setting the `\parindent` to zero, do not seem to help here.

Comment: `width=1.3\textwidth` <- the width of the pic is now 130 % of the printable space. And as you can see, the circle isn't a circle, since the height is much smaller. Use the option `keepaspectratio`.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify.

Comment: It's impossible to `center` something wider than `textwidth` because all paragraphs start after left margin. If your box is wider than text width it will take part of right margin as in your example. Try with `width=\textwidth` (or shorter) and will see how your figure is centered.

Answer (score 4):

You can call the frame (absolute) center:

```
\begin{filecontents}{circle}
    \documentclass[crop,preview,tikz]{standalone}
    \begin{document}% 
    \begin{tikzpicture}% 
        \draw (0,0) circle
        (1cm);% 
        \end{tikzpicture}% 
        \end{document}
    \end{circle}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usecolortheme{wolverine}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[
        mode=tex,
        width=1.3\textwidth,
        height=0.8\textheight
    ]{circle}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Title}
    \framesubtitle{Subtitle}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \node at (current page.center) {%
    \includestandalone[
        mode=tex,
        width=1\textwidth,
        height=0.8\textheight
    ]{circle}
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

A little y shifting would be necessary, though. This needs multiple run, two at least, maybe even three.

But to tell the truth, this seems to be a pretty awkward and annoying solution.

As suggested in your [linked thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29295/37907), a figure environment prevents the shifting. This might be a better solution.

Comment: If you use 1\textwidth then the normal centering command works aswell. Third comment at the question explains the issue.